# Как заменить все <item> на имена родителей в XML файле?

Tags: python, xml

Мне нужно импортировать XML файл с набором данных товаров, одна строка(товар) в данном файле выглядит так:

```
<root>
  <Big_Images>
    <item>https:// url.com/jpg1.com</item>
    <item>https:// url.com/jpg2.com</item>
    <item>https:// url.com/jpg3.com</item>
  </Big_Images>
  <Title>
    <item>Название</item>
  </Title>
  <Price>
    <item>9.99</item>
  </Price>
  <Main_Info>
    <item>
      &lt;div class="goodInfo"&gt; Куча html кода и текста &lt;/div&gt;
    </item>
  </Main_Info>
</root>
```

Проверял данный xml и он валиден, однако компонент ни в какую не хочет обрабатывать такую() формулировку.

В итоге надо убрать item и на их месте поставить имена "родителей" что бы было

```
<root>
  <Big_Images>https:// url.com/jpg1.com</Big_Images>
  <Big_Images>https:// url.com/jpg2.com</Big_Images>
  <Big_Images>https:// url.com/jpg3.com</Big_Images>
  <Title>Название</Title>
  <Price>9.99</Price>
  <Main_Info>
    &lt;div class="goodInfo"&gt; Куча html кода и текста &lt;/div&gt
  </Main_Info>
</root>
```

Возможно ли это реализовать и если да то как?